# Automorphism Aut/Inn/Out of the unitary group $U(N)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, automorphism-group

Given a group $G$, we denote the center Z$(G)$, we like to know the
automorphism group Aut($G$), the outer automorphism Out($G$) and the inner automorphism Inn($G$). They form short exact sequences:
$$
1 \to \text{Z}(G) \to G \to \text{Inn}(G) \to 1, \quad \text{and    } \quad
1 \to \text{Inn}(G) \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 1,
$$
and a combined exact sequence
$$
1 \to \text{Z}(G) \to G  \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 1.
$$

### Question:

For $G=U(N)$ as a [unitary group, a subgroup in GL$(N, \mathbb{C})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) represented by rank-$N$ unitary matrices of complex coefficients $\mathbb{C}$.

We know the center $Z(U(N))=U(1)$.

What are the follows:

- Aut($U(N)$) = ?
- Inn($U(N)$)= ?
- Out($U(N)$)= ?

For $G=U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$ where $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is a finite abelian group of order $k$, which requires $k \vert N$ to be factorized.

We know the center $Z(U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k)=U(1)$.

- Aut($U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$) = ?
- Inn($U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$)= ?
- Out($U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$)= ?

### Additional background info (warm-up, which I had obtained):

If $G$ is a simply-connected compact Lie group and ${\bf{g}}$ is its Lie algebra (which would necessarily be semi-simple),
then $\text{Inn}(G)=\text{Inn}({\bf g})=\mathrm{P}G$,
$\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Aut}({\bf g})$,
and
$ \text{Out}(G)=\text{Out}({\bf g})= \text{Aut}(D_{{\bf{g}} })$ is isomorphic to the automorphism group of the Dynkin diagram $D_{{\bf{g}} }$ of the Lie algebra ${\bf{g}} $.

- For $G=U(1)$, we have
  $\text{Z}(G) =U(1)$,
  $\text{Inn}(G) = 1$,
  $\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Out}(G) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.
- For $G=SU(2)$,
  we have
  $\text{Z}(G) =\mathbb{Z}_2$,
  $\text{Inn}(G) = SO(3)$,
  $\text{Aut}(G)=PSU(2)=SO(3)$, and
  $\text{Out}(G) = 1$.
- For $G=SU(N)$ with $N$ $\geq 3$,
  we have
  $\text{Z}(G) =\mathbb{Z}_{N}$,
  $\text{Inn}(G) = PSU(N)$,
  and
  $\text{Out}(G) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.
  We also have $\text{Aut}(G)=PSU(N) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: What field are we over here? If we're over $\mathbb{R}$, which is what I would guess from context, which unitary group are you interested in? $U(n)=U(n,0)$?

Comment: () is in GL$(n, \mathbb{C})$ --- a rank-$n$ matrice of complex coefficients $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If you mean $U(n)$, the compact group of unitary matrices, it is usually written down as complex matrices, but it's still a *real* Lie group. Please be more precise. (Many things are "in" $GL(n, \mathbb C)$).

Comment: Thanks, I did already give a Wiki link - I am talking about the most common unitary group written as $U(n)$

Comment: So do you guys know the answer?  

Aut(()) = ?

Inn(())= ?

Out(())= ?